# JavaScript to Handle REST JSON Feed

Tags: javascript, json, rest

Trying to figure out the JavaScript syntax for handling JSON feed returned by a REST service. Suppose a random REST service (e.g. http://random.service/directory) is returning the following feed:

```
{
  'firstName': 'John',
  'lastName': 'Smith',
  'address': {
      'streetAddress': '21 2nd Street',
      'city': 'New York'
  }
}
```

and that I have a JSON parsing JS function (to parse the above feed) like:

```
function parseRESTFeed(json) {
  ...
}
```

How do I bridge the REST call of "http://random.service/hello" to parseRESTFeed(json) via JS?

Much Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use jQuery (and you should if you don't), then you can do it like this ([ref](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)):

```
$.getJSON('http://random.service/directory', null, function(data){
    // And here you can do whatever you want with "data", no need to parse it
    alert(data.firstName);
});
```

If you have some other way to get response from the service as string, again there is no reason to parse, since you can use javascript's `eval`. For example:

```
var myJSON = "{'firstName': 'John','lastNAme': 'Smith'}";
var data = eval('(' + myJSON + ')');
alert(data.firstName);
```