# box.net v2 api rest endpoints

Tags: box-api

This may sound very stupid question , but I can't find any documentation that gives me this info :

I want to make calls to v2 api from javascript.What are the endpoints for it,I only get the cUrl in docs.I have the auth_token and api_key and want to upload a file to root folder.Post request to following url gives error:

```
https://www.box.com/api/2.0/files/content/0?api_key=<my_api_key>&auth_token=<my_auth_token>
```

response :

```
{
    "type": "error",
    "status": 401,
    "code": "invalid_authorization_header",
    "help_url": "http:\/\/developers.box.com\/docs\/#errors",
    "message": "\"Authorization\" header either missing or invalid",
    "request_id": "1208099125507c7b0670911"
}
```

also,is the JSONP supported by v2 api.I have to make a cross domain reuest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The api-key and auth-token need to be send in the header.   V2 APIs won't accept them in the GET parameters.

We don't currently support JSONP, but we are considering it as a post-GA add-on.

Can you please elaborate in how this doesn't work with javascript?  There are some javascript examples on other [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9481073/calling-rest-webservice-using-jquery-ajax-call-web-service-is-returning-json-s) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9959729/javascript-to-handle-rest-json-feed)  that may also help.

Comment: I hate when apis don't allow the javascript to use them

Comment: @vishesh If you're making an authorized request from a javascript client your auth information will be visible to the user if they monitor network traffic.  Do you have a good solution for avoiding that?